# Typecasting to int while searching for patterns with regex, avoiding immutability of tuples

Tags: python, casting

I'm currently working on a problem where I read lines from files, with lines formatted as such:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all   25399 Nov  2 21:25 exception_hierarchy.pdf
```

and the expected output is as list of correlating tuples, for example:

```
(25399, "Nov", 2, 21, 25, "exception_hierarchy.pdf")
```

I have accomplished this with regex matching, but my answer looks like:

```
("25399", "Nov", "2", "21", "25", "exception_hierarchy.pdf")
```

Is there any way to typecast the number strings to int during regex matching and get around the immutability of tuples? I have gone through my list of tuples and printed out only those number strings in each tuple, so I know I can access them. The problem is I tried to typecast to int and realized that nothing happens. Do I have to somehow copy the entire list of tuples? Seems very inefficient. Here is my code so far:

```
import re

def file_listing(filename="src/listing.txt"):

    tuple_list = []

    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        for lines in file:
            current_line = file.readline()
            found = re.search(r".* \d .* .* (\d+) (\w+) (\d+) (\d+):(\d+) (.*)", current_line)
            if found:
                found_groups = found.groups()
                for item in found_groups:
                    if item.isdigit():
                        print(item)          # Found the correct items, but...
                        #item = int(item)    # tuples are immutable!! find another way
                tuple_list.append(found_groups)

           

    return tuple_list

def main():
    print(file_listing())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're parsing the output of `ls -la` (which is distro-dependent) instead of `os.stat` or similar?

Comment: If you use "group(<idx>) instead of groups" you get a string which corresponds to the matched group, that you can cast and append. I am on my phone but I'll try to write an answer about it in an hour.

Comment: @SuperStormer I'm not sure what you mean by that, I'm not super well versed in this stuff. This is a MOOC exercise that I am completing and some stuff was given to me beforehand

Comment: Thanks, Fra93, if you see my reply to the post below, I have figured that out now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuple is a structure which is *unchangeable*. You have to create another tuple and add the new one to `tuple_list`. For example:

```py
tuple_list = []

groups = "25399", "Nov", "2", "21", "25", "exception_hierarchy.pdf"
tuple_list.append(tuple(map(lambda x: int(x) if x.isdigit() else x, groups)))

print(tuple_list)
```

Prints:

```py
[(25399, 'Nov', 2, 21, 25, 'exception_hierarchy.pdf')]
```

Comment: This worked for me. For future reference, now that I've passed the test I can see an example solution which typecasts to int on the individual groups from the group object that re.search found and then append a tuple like so:             t = m.groups()

            result.append((int(t[0]), t[1], int(t[2]), int(t[3]), int(t[4]), t[5]))